# How to rip two dvd's on the same disc?

Tags: handbrake

I'm trying to rip two movies on the same drive and I can't figure it out, handbrake keeps wanting to rip the first but not the second and I wanted to ask here if anyone knew how to rip the second movie, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

By default Handbrake selects the longest duration track, it assumes this is the main content - usually a DVD has one main feature, and then may have a bunch of smaller tracks (extras, trailers, intros, etc).

Using the "Title" drop-down near the top left of screen, you should just be able to select the other track. You could also use the Add To Queue -> Add All option to add everything from the disc to the encode queue in one batch.